# Datamining: Why use algorithms for large datasets instead of using predictions based on a sample?

Tags: clustering, data-mining, large-data

A growing amount of cluster algorithms have been developed for using large datasets such as [CURE](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=276312) or [BIRCH](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=233324) or filtering methods for common k-means. What is the advantage of using such an algorithm instead of talking a randomized sample from a large dataset for training purposes and then predict the cluster membership of the remaining data?

One could assume that cluster-solutions differ depending on the sample but if the sample is large enough to be representative for the whole population this should not be the case. I could imagine that for very small groups and outliers this might be still the case but it could be at least tested if drawing several randomized samples. Such an approach is implemented for example in the [CLARA algorithm](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Clustering/CLARA).

So why use potentially less efficient algorithms for the whole dataset if well established methods could work on a sample?

Comment: CURE and BIRCH are '90s techniques. I doubt your claim "growing amount" is correct. Most techniques you find are O(n^2) or even O(n^3) (e.g. meanshift, spectral, affinity propagation) and all but scalable to large datasets. IMHO it is common to only cluster a sample. Predicting the cluster membership of all data is actually quite uselessz because clusters rarely are perfect or even good. It's an explorative approach. You use it for *understanding* your data, not for labeling.